# QTP - Exception after upgrading to UFT 11.51

Tags: exception, patch, qtp, hp-uft

i have been working with UFT 11.50 (the new QTP 11.00) and recently have applied the patch UFT 11.51.

i have also applied the patch for ALM 11.51 and the Results viewer 11.51

I launch UFT and after opening a test (whichever) I get the following screen>

[image]

I am desperate to solve this and there is no (known to me) uninstallation method for the patches!

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE> After uninstalling the patches I get this>

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so we won't know what happened there...
I uninstalled everything and installed UFT from the beginning.

I also removed manually all registry entries plus HP directories (related to the product) before doing so.

I hope this helps if anybody comes up with the same problem.

PS> It takes about half a day to do all that so... make sure you have it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall UFT patches from the control panel->Uninstall a program, and then selecting "view installed updates" (on the left).
You should have the HP UFT service pack there, and should be able to uninstall from there.

Regarding the error you have recieved, it seems like you may have an issue with registration.

I believe that the problematic DLL may be: HP.QTP.DocumentWrappedObjects.dll

It should be located in your UFT installation bin directory.

You can try and call regsvr32.exe on it, to see if it successfully registers the dll, if you recieve any error, post it here.

Comment: "HP.QTP.DocumentWrappedObjects.dll" is not an executable file and no registration helper is registered for this file type.

Comment: I think I'll uninstall the patches. Very confusing indeed... Thanks for the help though.

Comment: OK I did uninstall them now I get the same screen with diffent text. This time the source is > HP.QTP.Backend.Features.FeaturesFactory and the explanation "Could not load file or assembly 'HP.QTP.Backend.Features.PersistenceFeature, Version=11.50.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest." - see original post for updates